# Create custom properties at runtime

Tags: c#, properties

I am trying to create a custom property (like Name, BackgroundImage etc.) for my dynamically created PictureBox called "angle". And use it like that:
`PictureBox.angle = 20;`
Is there a way to do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With "dynamically created PictureBox" you meant that you created a control from a certain UI Framework and created that without the help of a designer? Then add the used UI Framework as Tag.

Comment: C# is not a dynamic language. You can't add arbitrary properties to an object. Depending on the UI framework, it might have a `Tag` property that allows you to attach a single value to it, such as an object with the properties you need.

Comment: @madreflection You can absolutely add arbitrary properties to an object in C#. See `ExpandoObject` and the `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: @MatthewM.: Yes, but not just *any* type. Only those that support it. `PictureBox` certainly does not support it. Very few do.

Comment: Build a Custom Control derived from PictureBox that exposes whatever custom Properties / Methods you require. -- If you just need to associate some data to the Control, as already mentioned, the Tag Property can hold anything; i.e., a class object that carries whatever values you care about.

Comment: Actually, your your custom control can also implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` as in `class MyCustomPictureBoxb: PictureBox, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom component (Right click Project -> Add -> Component). Change it to inherit from `PictureBox`, and add the property.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Playground.WinForms
{
    public partial class MyCustomPictureBox : PictureBox
    {
        public int Angle { get; set; }

        public MyCustomPictureBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MyCustomPictureBox(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

When you build your WinForms solution, it will appear in your Toolbox, at which point your can drag it onto your form, or create one dynamically as you mentioned above.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };

// Rest the mouse pointer over v.Amount and v.Message in the following // statement to verify that their inferred types are int and string. 
Console.WriteLine(v.Amount + v.Message);
```

Try use anonynous types

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types

Comment: You've missed the point entirely. OP has an object of a *named* type, `PictureBox`, which provides specific UI functionality. An anonymous type acomplishes nothing.